# How to write this mysql query correctly?

Tags: mysql

How to write this mysql query correctly ?

```
SELECT order_id FROM order_details WHERE tracking_id = substr('420342389400110200882112625820',-LENGTH(tracking_id))
```

The query should match 42034238 **9400110200882112625820** from the tracking_id

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the RIGHT function:

```
SELECT order_id
FROM order_details
WHERE tracking_id = RIGHT('420342389400110200882112625820',LENGTH(tracking_id))
```

Comment: This query doesnt work but this one works SELECT order_id
FROM cscart_order_details
WHERE tracking_id = RIGHT('420342389400110200882112625820',22)

Comment: somehow LENGTH(tracking_id) is not being parsed.

Comment: Does tracking_id have any leading / trailing spaces?

Comment: You are right because of some empty rows it was return a lot of rows. thanks . accepting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT order_id
FROM order_details
WHERE tracking_id = RIGHT('420342389400110200882112625820',LENGTH(tracking_id))
```

> MySQL RIGHT() extracts a specified number of characters from the right
>   side of a string.

refer [**MySQL RIGHT()**](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-right-function.php)

Comment: @shikhar:didn't my answer and link helped you..??